# Haskell this file's path

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to get the path of the file where the function is defined?

For example:

```
rootappdir
|- Foo.hs
|- Bar.hs


module Foo where

getThisDir :: IO Filepath
getThisDir = ...

prelude> getThisDir
absolute/path/to/rootappdir/Foo.hs
```

If it is possible with an even simpler function :: Filepath, that's even better.
Maybe we would need to use the preprocessor?

Comment: I don't know what you need this for but I think at least the absolute path is not the best idea - why should your code behave differently if I/you choose to move the files into another path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use Template Haskell to do this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Functor
import Language.Haskell.TH
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath

filePath :: String
filePath = $(do
    dir <- runIO getCurrentDirectory
    filename <- loc_filename <$> location
    litE $ stringL $ dir </> filename)
```

Comment: Thank you! I would upvote this answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: let me do it for you ;)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can't get this information in run-time. But you can get it in compile-time through Template Haskell using function `Language.Haskell.TH.location` or `qLocation`.

If you need logging functionality you can use [package monad-logger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger). You can find an example of using `qLocation` there.